# Deleting first node in link address and getting illegal address on function return

Tags: c

Delete node function deletes a given node from a link list. The function correctly deletes any node except the head node. The link list (head) has 6 nodes 0,1,2,3,4,5. the delete function correctly returns a new link list with the node deleted. For example if I want to delete node 2 it will return 0,1,3,4,5.
For node one, it return a number, -572662307 for the first node and crashes when I try to print the list out after it returns the link list head. It works on all nodes but the head node.
I have reviewed other code and cant figure out whats going on.

```
deleteNode(MainNode * head, MainNode * todelete)
{

    int headvalue;
    MainNode *temp = head;
    MainNode *prev = head;

    headvalue = todelete->value;

    // If head node itself holds the value to be deleted 
    if (temp != NULL && temp-> value == headvalue)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head -> next;   // Changed head from node 0 to node 1

     // orginal list 0,1,2,3,4,5. Print in the function 1,2,3,4,5 correctly
        printlist(head);
        free(temp); // free old head
     // when
        return head;
    }

    // Search for the value to be deleted
    while (temp != NULL && temp->value != todelete->value)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
     //If not present in linked list 
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        return head;
    }

      // Unlink the node from linked list 
    prev -> next = temp->next;

    // free memory
    free(temp); 

return head;
}
```

Comment: The function you show, is it the full and actual function in your real code? Without any return-type declaration? And how do you call this function? Please create a [mcve] to show us. And please read (or refresh) [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: But if I should ***guess***, it would be that you don't use what the function returns, which means all changes to the *local* variable `head` inside the function will be lost.

Comment: When using older C compiler (or when running  "K&R" more), the compiler will assume int return type. Follow the comment above to add a type, and force the compiler to run in C99 or 'strict' mode. It will leverage type checking, and save you lot of time!